# Login with user and polymorphic stuff (Rails 4)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my Rails application, I have introduced a way to log-in from different user groups.

I have an User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    ....

    belongs_to :operator, polymorphic: true 

end
```

and different groups model, for example Admins, Clients, Workers, all with a:

```
....
has_one :user, as: :operator
```

Active Record association.

All works great but I have a problem with sign-in of a new user.

Assuming we want to create a new Client.
In my Clients_controller.rb I have

```
.
.
.
def create
        @client = Client.new(client_params)
        @user = User.new(user_params)
        if @client.save && @client.create_user(user_params)
            redirect_to @client
        else
            render 'new'
        end
    end

    private
        def user_params
            params.require(:user).permit(:username, :password, :password_confirmation)
        end

        def client_params
            params.require(:client).permit(:description)
        end
end
```

and (for completeness), this is the new.html.erb associated (labels are in Italian:

```
<div class ="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offet-3 box">
        <%= form_for @client do |f| %>
            <%= render 'shared/error_messages' %>
            <%= f.label 'Nome Azienda' %>
            <%= f.text_field :description, class: 'form_control' %>
            <%= fields_for @user do |g| %>
                <%= g.label 'inserire una username' %>
                <%= g.text_field :username, class: 'form_control' %>
                <%= g.label 'inserire una password' %>
                <%= g.password_field :password, class: 'form_control' %>
                <%= g.label 'ripetere la password' %>
                <%= g.password_field :password_confirmation, class: 'form_control' %>
            <% end %>
            <%= f.submit "Crea l'account", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
        <% end %>
    </div>
</div>
```

Main problem is that the condition:

> if @client.save && @client.create_user(user_params)

is always `true`, but if the `user_params` do not satisfy the validation, user is not created (while, when the `user_params` are ok, the user is correctly created and the one-to-one polymorphic association with client correctly established).

Side problem is that I don't know a way to capture both client-errors and user-error messages in the html interface. Actually this is the shared/_error_messages.html.erb

```
 <% if @client.errors.any? %>
      <div id="error_explanation">
        <div class="alert alert-danger">
          The form contains <%= pluralize(@client.errors.count, "error") %>.
        </div>
        <ul>
        <% @client.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
          <li><%= msg %></li>
        <% end %>
        </ul>
      </div>
    <% end %>
<% if @user.errors.any? %>
  <div id="error_explanation">
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
      The form contains <%= pluralize(@user.errors.count, "error") %>.
    </div>
    <ul>
    <% @user.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
      <li><%= msg %></li>
    <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

that is rendered into new.html.erb . I know is not so elegant and also it doesn't show all errors at the same time: if there is a problem with client validation *and* errors in user validation, the user errors related are now showed.

Comment: I would go ahead and explicitly save both models. If one fails, then both will fall out of the transaction and then you will not miss any validation errors.

Comment: I have follow your idea and i've added a .save:  if @client.save && @client.create_user(user_params).save ... It runs, indeed, but it is weird to save again for force the check. Now the problem is to capture the errors from that call. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your create method as

```
def create
  @client = Client.new(client_params)
  @user = User.new(user_params)
  @errors = [] 
  if @client.save && @user.save
    @client.user.save  = @user
    @client.save
    redirect_to @client
  else
    @errors << @client.errors.full_messages if @client.errors.any?
    @errors << @user.errors.full_messages if @user.errors.any?          
    render 'new'
   end
 end
```

And modify views to use @errors in new

Comment: Your idea is interesting. Problem is capture errors from @client.create_user(..).save

Answer (score 0):

There is an ActiveRecord action called transaction which would solve part of your problem that involves saving only if *all* affected records validate. All actions within the transaction block must be completed successfully or the db will roll back all actions in transaction.

```
def create
  @client.transaction do
        @client = Client.new!(client_params)
        @user = User.new!(user_params)
  end
end
```

More here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html

Comment: I'm not sure it is useful. I have no a "false" condition to be managed conveniently from controller, and i cannot capture errors for the feedback.  I can manage exceptions but it feels as a big increase of difficult. The rollback is not the main problem.

Comment: Okay. I don't think I understand your question then. But hopefully you will get an answer.

Answer (score 0):

OK, i've resolved taking some ideas from your answers and with this code:

```
def create
        @client = Client.new(client_params)
        @user = @client.create_user(user_params)
        if @client.save && @user.save
            redirect_to @client
        else
            @client.destroy
            render 'new'
        end
    end
```

It is weird i need to save again the "create_user" action, but it resolve the needing. Also, it produce all errors that can be conveniently displayed.